# Do I need to redefine preprocessor defines in parent projects?

Tags: c++, compilation

Maybe since I could not find the right keywords, I was unable to clarify my doubt on google.

Let say I have 2 C++ projects; **projA** and **projB**.
In a **exmpl.h** file in projA, there is this condition:

```
class myClass
{
...
#ifdef MYVAR
virtual ~myClass() {}
#endif
}
```

I define `MYVAR` as a project setting and compile projA to generate **projA.a** static library.

Now, from projB, I need to use `exmpl.h` of projA. Simply I include it and compile projB using projA.a static library.

However, imagine that in projB I did **not define** `MYVAR`.

- What would happen in this case? Does projB skip the code within `#ifdef`, but uses a static library which do was compiled with the code within `#ifdef`?
- So, is this an error and would cause unexpected behavior?
- Do we have to define all preprocessor defines which were used in sub-projects, also in all projects that use them?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh my. Just don't do that. Looks like a serious XY problem.

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions of `myClass` used in both projects must be the same, otherwise it's a violation of [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), causing undefined behavior, no diagnostic required (that is, the compiler isn't required to tell you about the violation).

So yes, you must define `MYVAR` in projB, as well as other defines affecting the definitions used in both projects.

This applies of course, only for entities ODR-used in both projects.

Comment: What is proper way when one wants to distribute projA? Just tell to users what they should define? Or is there any other practice?

Comment: @MertMertce if you distribute in binary form you shouldn't have any defines like this. If you distribute in source form, you can add a config.h file where these macros are defined, and require the users to #include it in their code.